# Reset an object without invoking copy constructor?

Tags: c++

I have an object that cannot be copied, a NetGame because it has a stringstream in it.

I have it declared in my class as:

```
NetGame m_game;
```

Later in the code, I just want to reset it, which should not need to copy anything.

```
void ServerTable::setActive( bool active )
{
    //reset for now
    if(m_active && !active)
    {
        m_inProgress = false;
        m_game = NetGame();
    }

    m_active = active;
}
```

What can I do to do this without heap reallocation each time?

I could make it a pointer and simply new, delete each time but that shouldn't be necessary in this case. I'm not using polymorphism.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just put in a `reset` function that does what a default constructor would do.

Comment: I know it is stack allocation, but I could use heap allocation to solve the problem.

Comment: There are too many variables (class ones that I do not initialize in the constructor).

Comment: Sorry, that sentence came through the wrong way then.

Comment: The class does inherit, but does not use polymorphism.

Comment: @Milo: What is your definition of *reset*? If your constructor does not initialize some of the variables, how do you expect to *reset* them? (i.e. they will be uninitialized on construction)...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, Technically in C++11, you can initialize them right in the declaration. I'm not sure if that's the case here, though. I can't think of anything better you could do than going through each one if you can't delegate.

Comment: @chris: That is syntactic sugar... that initialization is moved automagically to the initializer list in each constructor that does not provide an alternative value in it's own initialization list.

Comment: So there is no way to do whatever new operator does except you already know where to put the object?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I'm not sure how I forgot that, seeing as how it's why it works.

Comment: @Milo: There is a way (I have added as an answer), but while that technically is doable, I don't think it is a good idea (i.e. redesigning might be a much better idea)

Comment: @Milo: please clarify why can't you create `reset()` method and provide code example for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't think the question makes much sense. You claim that the object has many fields that are not initialized in the constructor, and that in turn means that your code will not touch those fields... so the definition of *reset* does not seem to be precise.

At any rate, technically you can call the destructor and then construct in place:

```
m_game.~NetGame();
new (&m_game) NetGame();
```

Technically you don't even need to call the destructor if it does not have side effects or if the program does not depend on such side effects... but I would call the destructor anyway *if* you decide to follow this path.

But I urge you to reconsider the design and actually offer a `reset()` member function that initializes all the members of `NetGame` that need to be reset.

Comment: For example, you would not initialize a std vector, but you do use it.

Comment: @Milo: `std::vector` has a default constructor, whether you mention it in the constructor or not, it will be called in the initialization list, so the constructor *does* initialize that member.

Comment: Then all my members are initialized by that definition. I do not want to make a reset method because then I must maintain it and it is error prone.

Comment: Is delegating to a constructor inside of a `reset` function possible/desirable? Something in the back of my mind keeps saying it's a bad idea.

Comment: @chris: If you mean *delegating constructor* as used in C++11, no, that cannot be done. On the other hand, weird as it is, destroying the object and recreating it --as far as you do not attempt to access any member in between-- even from a member function of that object is completely weird, dangerous and allowed (I believe). Object lifetime rules are *interesting*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I mean like `void reset() { NetGame(); /* possibly other stuff */ }` It seems like it would act like any other function call, but then again constructors are special, and that definitely isn't something you see every day (that's an understatement, too).

Comment: @chris: No you cannot call a constructor directly the syntax in your comment creates a temporary `NetGame` object and has no other effect. What you can do is use placement new to achieve that effect: `void reset() { /*1*/ new (this) NetGame(); }`. You *should* call the destructor first (in 1), but you are not required to if your program does not depend on the side effects of the destructor (this is *weird*: it's allowed even if there are side effects if you don't depend on them). At any rate `void NetGame::reset() { this->~NetGame(); new (this) NetGame(); }` is allowed and well defined.

Comment: I see, that's the only way. Is there a specific reason you can't actually call it, but you can call the destructor?

Comment: @chris: Placement new **is** a call to the constructor over already allocated memory. Funny syntax, but that is the syntax in the standard. My bet is that the standard does not allow the *more natural* syntax `ptr->NetGame()` for the simple reason that before the constructor completes, the object is not alive and you cannot *call a member function*, maintaining a separate syntax emphasizes this fact.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, Thanks, that pretty much clears it up. I've seen placement new, but never actually used it as of yet, and when you go through logically, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a reset method for class NetGame.

```
void NetGame::reset()
{
/*u can just reset the attribute u need*/
}
```

Then you can invoke the method in the setAcitvity function.

```
void ServerTable::setActive( bool active )
{
    //reset for now
    if(m_active && !active)
    {
        m_inProgress = false;
    }
    m_active.reset();
}
```